# Run a Python process and call function of THAT process externally

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I'm trying to make a program (with GUI) that shows some informations.
I would like to update these informations from outside events.

e.g.
I have another script that do his tasks once a day (once a day a NEW process runs and does it's job), after this job completes I would like to update the informations in my GUI,that is always displayed on my monitor,without closing and reopening it.

Is there a way to retrieve the GUI process from outside and run functions inside it? (or a better way if u can help me)

I dont even know where to start, I feel that is something with threading,but dont know how to proper do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  While I'm not entirely sure if it's even possible to do that; what you can do is have the GUI app check for specific semaphore files and when detected,  update the UI as necessary with whatever info is stored in the semaphore/temp files.   Just a possible way.

Comment: Are you looking for [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)?

Comment: Yes,I'm looking for a way to collect data in some way from external processes

Comment: I don't have time to answer, but what you are asking is, how to make and use a _service._ You need a thread in your GUI program that _listens_ on a _socket_ for incoming connections from client programs, and handles _requests_ from the client by calling whatever interesting function. There's a lot of ways to do that, and a lot of libraries and frameworks to support it. One way would be to implement a _RESTful_ service. Another would be to expose a _remote procedure call_ (RPC) interface.